# Android JavaLaunchHelper exception when running tests

Tags: android, exception, testing

I'm getting the following error frequently when I'm trying to run tests:

```
objc[4168]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Cleaning the project always fixes this issue, but that's annoying to have to do frequently. I'm guessing there's some strange behavior with the cache, but I'm not entirely sure. Can someone point me in the right direction?